# Creating a input mask in excel to insert new code/ new parameters for a code in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What i want to do, is to create a a VBA code for an input mask in excel, which should always save the word entered as a paramter and that it belongs to a certain group (department) e.g. Product: Audi A1, Department: Car production.

Simultaneously it should create a code automatically and insert it on a certain position. The code below should be inserted on a certain position in the same form as below after the content of the input masked is safed. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the code that should be inserted:

```vb
Sub SalesCarProduction() 
  'Parameters for searching strings
  Dim SalesCarProduction As String
  Dim AUDIa1 As String 

  'Parameters for saving the sales the devision 
  Dim Revenue_AudiA1 As Integer 
  Dim i As Integer 

  strDepartment = "Car Production" 
  strAudiA1 = "Audi A1" 

  For i = 1 To 10000 
    If Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1).Text = strDepartment And Tabelle1.Cells(i, 4).Text = strAudiA1 
    Then Revenue_AudiA1 = CLng(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 6).Value) * Tabelle1.Cells(i, 10).Value 
    End If 
  Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: This code should be inserted: Sub SalesCarProduction() 'Parameters for searching strings Dim SalesCarProduction As String Dim AUDIa1 As String 'Parameters for saving the sales the devision Dim Revenue_AudiA1 As Integer Dim i As Integer strDepartment = "Car Production" strAudiA1 = "Audi A1" For i = 1 To 10000 If Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1).Text = strDepartment And Tabelle1.Cells(i, 4).Text = strAudiA1 Then Revenue_AudiA1 = CLng(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 6).Value) * Tabelle1.Cells(i, 10).Value End If Next i End Sub

Comment: Yes, you can do that yourself, just click on [edit] and insert the code :) I could do that too, but it is hard to paste from your comment and add all the linebreaks and so on :)

Comment: @SebastianRupp, please check if the code was correctly added.

Comment: @OcasoProtal I think i miscommunicated :D. I meant that i want to be able to add endless car and devisions and combinations of cars and divisions very easily without programming knowledge, through an input mask and clicking safe. -> than the code should be generated by itself (Like a predefined code with placeholders which gets bigger and bigger by adding more products. Is that possible?